# How to stop form from not submitting based on input provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, input, mithril.js

So i have my form which i have created. As soon as i input Can't log in in the title or description section , the form will not submit , otherwise it will. I am not really sure of why this behaviour is happening. So far my code is as follows :

```
const m = require('mithril')

class IssueEditor {
  constructor(vnode) {
    this.title = vnode.attrs.title
    this.descriptionText = vnode.attrs.descriptionText
    this.onSubmit = vnode.attrs.onSubmit
  }
  view() {
    return m('form', {onsubmit: e => this.onSubmit({title: this.title, descriptionText: this.descriptionText})}, [
      m('.form-group', [
        m('label', {'for': 'title-input'}, 'Issue Title'),
        m('input.form-control#title-input', {value: this.title, oninput: (e) => {this.title = e.target.value}})
      ]),
      m('.form-group', [
        m('label', {'for': 'description-input'}, 'Description'),
        m('textarea.form-control#description-input', {oninput: (e) => {this.descriptionText = e.target.value}}, this.descriptionText)
      ]),
      m('button.btn.btn-primary#save-button', {type: 'submit'}, 'Save')
    ])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onsubmit` function, you probably need an `e.preventDefault()` to stop Javascript from automatically submitting the form, rather than using your `vnode.attrs.onSubmit` function.

So change

```
{onsubmit: e => this.onSubmit({title: this.title, descriptionText: this.descriptionText})}, [
```

to

```
{ onsubmit: e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.onSubmit({ title: this.title, descriptionText: this.descriptionText })
}}, [
```